# Highcharts Waterfall: How to calculate difference between absolute values automatically?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Consider the following fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/waterfall/

```
data: [{
        name: 'Start',
        y: 120000
    }, {
        name: 'Product Revenue',
        y: 569000
    }, {
        name: 'Service Revenue',
        y: 231000
    }, {
        name: 'Positive Balance',
        isIntermediateSum: true,
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
    }, {
        name: 'Fixed Costs',
        y: -342000
    }, {
        name: 'Variable Costs',
        y: -233000
    }, {
        name: 'Balance',
        isSum: true,
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
    }]
```

Here, the y values are given as a difference i.e. increments and decrements. The data set which I have is a set of absolute values like 1000, 2000, 1800, 1500, 3000... and not the differences. Is it possible that Highcharts calculate the differences from these values automatically (i.e. 1000, 1000, -200, -300, 1500.. for the above example)? Or is it not supported yet?

Comment: Waterfall requires diffs, if you have this dataset you can use columnrange series (connector will be missing though).

Comment: @PawełFus Okay. Actually, I was thinking on lines of AnyChart library which supports this https://playground.anychart.com/docs/8.2.0/samples/BCT_Waterfall_Chart_02

Comment: Thanks! No, such thing is not supported - nobody has ever asked for this feature according to our [UserVoice](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api?query=waterfall). Feel free to create an idea there! :)